# HSQLDB: create schema if not exists -> unexpected token not

Tags: java, hsqldb

I can't find a way to create schema only if it doesn't exist.

I tried:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS temp
```

but get unexpected token :`NOT` error.

However, dropping schema works ok

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS temp
```

Comment: Is this an in memory database?

Comment: Where [in the manual](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_schema_creation) did you find the `if exists` option?

Comment: This is not currently supported but will be supported in the next version 2.4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature will be supported in the next version, 2.4.0.